# How to add APC adapter to cache classmaps in Zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, apc, zend-cache, zend-config

I need to cache classmaps of each of my modules in my Zend framework 2 application using APC in opcode cache .  Is there a work around for this .

AFAIK in the application.config.php

> ```
>    'module_map_cache_enabled' => true,
> ```
>
> // The key used to create the class map cache file name.
>           'module_map_cache_key' => 'test',
>
> // The path in which to cache merged configuration.
>
> ```
>   'cache_dir' => 'path/to/data/cache',
> ```

By doing so Zend cache is using file system to cache I need it to use APC opcode cache how can I achive that .

I know to use APC in zend framework 1 at bootstrap.php .

But for this I am not finding any documentation in the official site .

Thanks in advance for responding to this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated file **will** be cached by the APC opcode cache if you have the opcode cache enabled. You can check this by looking at the [apc statistics page](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/apc/trunk/apc.php?view=log). Place this file temporarely on your server and watch the `system cache entries` tab.
The module map and config cache does only support files and no cache adapters implementing the StorageInterface.

Comment: I think you are still confusing APC opcode cache and APC user/data cache. With the opcode cache opcodes are saved into APC (skipping the parsing and compilation process). If configured right (`apc.enabled = 1`, `apc.cache_by_default = 1`) the classmap file should be automaticly saved in the opcode cache. You also want to look into the `apc.stat` directive, it is recommended to set this to 0 on production to further reduce calls to the filesystem.

Comment: My question is about how to setup class maps of zend framework 2 to cache into opcode cache . not how to configure APC

Comment: You have told if configured right what actually you meant by that, where I have to set those parameters actually .

Comment: You can set the directives in your php.ini or /etc/php.d/apc.ini depending on your PHP installation. You only have to make sure apc opcode cache is turned on here, php will take care of caching your classmap.

Comment: Hey Thank you very much for clear explaination , it worked out for me I am able to see classmaps in the apc.php system cache entries thanks